# When does the model() hook in the route handler get called anyway? Does it get called in a link-to in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I read this online in a tutorial:

> Because we supplied a model to the link (book.author), Ember is not
>   calling the model() hook and therefore no question arises about
>   reloading data. Our fix is simple enough: pass in book.author.id so
>   that model() gets called.

I am trying to overwrite the shouldBackgroundReloadRecord hook in an author.js adapter, which I think only gets called when the model() hook gets called with findRecord... but I never see the console.log message which makes me think the model hook isn't being called in the route handler:

> This method is used by the store to determine if the store should
>   reload a record after the store.findRecord method resolves a cached
>   record.
>
> This method is only checked by the store when the store is returning a
>   cached record.
>
> If this method returns true the store will re-fetch a record from the
>   adapter.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({

  shouldReloadRecord(store, snapshot) {
    return false;
  },

  shouldBackgroundReloadRecord(store, snapshot) {
    console.log("Calling shouldBackgroundReloadRecord");
    const loadedAt = snapshot.record.get('loadedAt');

    // if it was loaded more than an hour ago
    if (Date.now() - loadedAt > 3600000) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

});
```

This is my templates/books.hbs with the link-to:

```
{{!-- app/templates/books.hbs --}}
...
{{#link-to 'author' book.author.id class="author" bubbles=false }}{{book.author.name}}{{/link-to}}
...
```

To my understanding, anytime we click a link-to, we hit the router.js, which then determines what route-handler gets called. When a route-handler gets called, doesn't the model() hook get called in the route handler?

My route handler for author is pretty normal and pretty irrelevant probably, but here it is.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('author', params.author_id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you consult the [Ember.Route#model](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) documentation:

> Note that for routes with dynamic segments, this hook is not always executed. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper or the transitionTo method of routes), and a model context is already provided this hook is not called.
>
> A model context does not include a primitive string or number, which does cause the model hook to be called.

Followed by code samples and whether they trigger or not the model hook.

Answer (score 1):

When you change query params through a link-to, it is not considered a full transition. This means that no Route method hook like model will be called.
If you need a query param change to trigger a full transition, and thus the method hooks, you can use the optional queryParams configuration hash on the Route. If you have a authoerId query param and you want it to trigger a model refresh, you can set it as

//Route

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    authorId: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },

  model({ authorId }) {
    return this.store.findRecord('author', authorId);
  }
});
```

// Controller

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['authorId'],
  authorId: null
});
```